# Can I use GPU as GPGPU on any system

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, gpgpu

I wish to use the GPU of a system as GPGPU. The machine is remote, I don't have administrative rights and I don't know anything about its drivers. What I know is that it has has a Matrox VGA card. Can I use as GPGPU with C code and gcc compiler or do I need to have some kind of drivers? Or can I only use OpenGL and twist the logic to suit my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this using OpenGL. It would be easy to do this if you know the graphics card supports GPGPU functionality. i.e. CUDA, OpenCL, or AMD stream. Then you can use one of these APIs to write a program which uses GPU for computation. For, this you will need corresponding SDKs. But, even using this APIs it is non-trivial to use GPU for complex calculations.

Answer (score 1):

A few Matrox video cards support OpenGL and/or DirectX, so you might get away with what you want to do through shaders written in **OpenGL/GLSL** or **DirectX/HLSL**.

Check the specification of your video card.

Warning: these cards are not known to have particularly good GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OpenCL/CUDA/Stream capabilities of a Graphics card requires drivers that expose the functionality. Aside from that, older cards (like say the ATI X800 series) do not have the required hardware to efficiently do what GPGPU requires, and thus are unusable for such purposes.

I doubt Matrox VGA cards have any support for GPGPU whatsoever.